# Changing the dropdown value on click of radio button

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using spring with ibatis and jsp page for presentation. My question is I have one jsp page and the value of a drop list I am rendering through the model attribute, as shown below.

```
<select id="describe" style="width: 500px;">
    <c:forEach var="aff" items="${droplist}">
        <option name="category" value="${aff.community_category_id}">
            ${aff.category}
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

And here is my radio button:

```
<input type="radio" id="class" name="type" value="1" checked>Class
<input type="radio" id="Club" name="type" value="2">Club
<input type="radio" id="Course" name="type" value="3">Course
<input type="radio" id="Community" name="type" value="4">Community
```

On clicking any radio button it needs to change the content of the dropdown list.

Any idea I am not getting.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to change all the `<option>` items within the `<select>` list, or just select a specific `<option>` that's already propagated in the `<select>` list?

Comment: no once the page is load the drop down contain the 5 list  "suppose"  a,b,c d,e" by default "a" is visible and when any of radio button i.e "club" is checked  den visible list will be "d" not "a".means automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <head>
            <title>prova</title>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                    var listA=[{name:'name1a', value:'value1a'}, {name:'name2a', value:'value2a'}, {name:'name3a', value:'valuea3a'}];
                    var listB=[{name:'name1b', value:'value1b'}, {name:'name2b', value:'value2b'}, {name:'name3b', value:'valuea3b'}];
                    var listC=[{name:'name1c', value:'value1c'}, {name:'name2c', value:'value2c'}, {name:'name3c', value:'valuea3c'}];
            </script>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(
                    function() {
                            $(':radio').bind('click',function(){
                                    $('#describe')
                                            .find('option')
                                            .remove()
                                            .end();
                                    $.each(listA, function(index, value) {
                                            $('#describe').append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
                                    });

                            });
                    });
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div>
            <select id="describe">
                    <option name="name" value="1">a</option>
                    <option name="name" value="2">b</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                    <input type="radio" id="class" name="type" value="1" checked>Class <br/>
                    <input type="radio" id="Club" name="type" value="2" >Club<br/>
                    <input type="radio" id="Course" name="type" value="3">Course<br/>
                    <input type="radio" id="Community" name="type" value="4">Community<br/>
            </div>
    </body>
```

this'll just change the content of the describe selet every time you click on one of the radio button and load new values/names taken from listA object